# Global ExceptionHandling in Python Project

Tags: python, exception

I have  a python project with many .py files. I want to implement a global exception handling mechanism in Python so that if any error occurs, the error handling file is called and a common mechanism can be followed.

Comment: "`.ps` files" - what, like PostScript, the printing file format? Did you mean `.py`?

Comment: A global handler like this is pretty much only good for making the shutdown prettier and maybe logging error details. There's no way to slap a global "make it work" handler or a "screw the errors, keep going!" handler on your program. People have tried exception handling systems that let you resume at the error location after an exception, and it turns out that's a terrible idea.

Comment: @user2357112: Yes, I mean .py files. My concern is that I don't want to write try in every file in my python project. So I want to write a common exception handling code in a single .py file. And based on where the error occurs the mechanism can be different. I am new to Python. What is the standard practice to handle and log exceptions in large Python projects

Comment: Trying to put all your `try` logic in one place is like trying to put all your `if` logic in one place. Write the handling where it needs to go. Trying to centralize it is futile.

Comment: @BhavnaBeri: I personally prefer a very localized (line-level) try-catch blocks. Most of the times I wrap it in a module level exception when the exception crosses the module boundary. Application level error handler is probably not a good idea, unless you want a shutdown hook.